# Any design pattern to declare helper object for AngularJs controller?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to encapsulate complexity of interacting with some third-party `UI` component in a separate `JavaScript` object (sort of `adapter`), in a separate js file to simplify my AngularJs controller. However I do not want this object to be a service as it's to be used by the specific controller only, and I want it to be wiped off from memory along with the controller.
 From AngularJs best code practices point, should I just declare it in a separate file as a simple object without any references to Angular specific stuff, or should I declare it somehow inside the same module and pass it to my controller via dependency injection? Is there any specific AngularJs pattern regarding such helper/adapter objects?

Comment: Angular services are singletons. You are not gaining anything from memory consumption if you declare it as a service vs. a standalone function. Also, controllers should not be interacting with UI components - controllers are View-agnostic.

Answer (score 0):

Even though you said you don't want it to be a service, I still think you need a service. (*edit* Removed my previous comment here. The service won't be GC'd. It's going to be a singleton). Your service wouldn't be GC'd, but if the service has a method that returns a new object with your helper methods on it, then at least THAT can be GC'd.

Since Angular is an opinionated framework, then of COURSE you should create it within Angular and not as a regular object outside of Angular.

Whether or not you put it in its own file is largely personal preference, though my preference is to put all classes (or class-like definitions) in their own file.

Comment: This is entirely inaccurate to say that "Service" would be GC'ed whereas "Factory" would not. `.factory` and (unfortunately named) `.service` define methods of instantiating the Service *singleton* object that will be injected throughout the app. However you instantiate it gives the same Service object.

Comment: Ugh... you're totally right. I should have read the whole post.